# How to set findViewById correct in my onClick function

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem with my "findViewById" and it is occuring between the line.

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailShareHoldingActivity.this).setTitle("Köp " + Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getName() +  " Aktier").setView(addView).setPositiveButton("Köp", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

and the line

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
```

If I place the line any other where it works fine, problem is that I must have the line exactly where I have it, so I don't know why its complaining?
Here is my OnclickListener

```
buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText tempEditText;    
        final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shop_exsisting_share, null);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailShareHoldingActivity.this).setTitle("Köp " + Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getName() +  " Aktier").setView(addView).setPositiveButton("Köp", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            tempEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nrOfSharesInPortfolioEdit);//Complains on findViewById "Return type for the method is missing" and I have to have the code exactly here so that it is visible when the dialog is created and not when the button is pressed.
            tempEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nrOfSharesInPortfolioEdit);
            tempEditText.setText(Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getNrOfSharesInPortfolio());
            System.out.println(Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getNrOfSharesInPortfolio());
            tempEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currentCourseEdit);
            tempEditText.setText(Double.toString(Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getCurrentRate()));

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                System.out.println("Button pressed köp ");
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Avbryt", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you're having problems. You're trying to define already-declared variables within a class definition... which isn't allowed.

Your comment says, "*I have to have the code exactly here so that it is visible when the dialog is created and not when the button is pressed.*". This doesn't make any sense; you need to have your code in an actual method.

Move your definitions outside of the class definition and into a method instead.

```
tempEditText = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.nrOfSharesInPortfolioEdit);
tempEditText = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.nrOfSharesInPortfolioEdit);
tempEditText.setText(Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getNrOfSharesInPortfolio());
System.out.println(Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getNrOfSharesInPortfolio());
tempEditText = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.currentCourseEdit);
tempEditText.setText(Double.toString(Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getCurrentRate()));

new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailShareHoldingActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Köp " + Portfolio.getPortfolio().getShareHolding(positionList).getName() +  " Aktier")
    .setView(addView)
    .setPositiveButton("Köp", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            System.out.println("Button pressed köp ");
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Avbryt", null)
    .show();
```

Comment: Shouldn't all the `findViewById()`s be `addView.findViewById()`s?

Comment: @RaghavSood Yup, fixed. Thanks.